# Clang 3.3 and Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, clang, c++builder

I'm using Embarcaderos C++ Builder, that comes with a Clang 3.3 compiler. 
Its CMake support is somewhat broken, causing problems compiling 3rd party libraries.

I'm looking into using Visual Studio, with a separate installation of (native) Clang (3.3) because of the above, in order to compile 3rd party libraries. These compiled libraries could then (hopefully!) be used, consumed by Embarcadero Clang.

Does anyone know if its feasible to configure Visual Studio for Clang 3.3, or if it only works for later versions of Clang?

On Clang/LLVM website, there are no Windows binaries for version 3.3, only for later versions.

Also, would binaries generated, by Clang (3.3) + VS, be usable by Embarcadero Clang(3.3) + C++ Builder?

Comment: I may be wrong, but the Clang compilers that come with C++Builder are probably modified to be able to use Delphi code. I doubt you can use these with VS.

Comment: Yeah that sounds probable. However, my idea is to use a native installation of Clang with visual studio, not Embarcaderos Clang. I have clarified that in my question.

Comment: But the native installation will probably not be able to compile C++Builder-specific code, which is able to interface with Delphi. For that, you probably need the modified Clang and specific runtime libraries. Now, if the 3rd party libraries are pure C++, then it could work.

Comment: Yeah, only thinking of 3rd  party, C/C++, libraries